# Create my own proxy server by using AWS Linux EC2 instance, Error: The connection has timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, curl, http-proxy

I have tried to create my own proxy server by using AWS Linux EC2 instance. I followed the steps from this [article](https://dev.to/viralsangani/be-anonymous-create-your-own-proxy-server-with-aws-ec2-2k63) and this [article](https://medium.com/@ihimanshurawat/how-to-setup-a-proxy-server-on-ec2-655db0c873d8). ([Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wGRByZDOIQhz5G_JfzzbjIilSFpjlRFv/view?usp=sharing) is all the details and screenshots of steps) But after create the instance and configure the Tinyproxy and then configure browser to this proxy, it shows me an error. When I open the browser and try to search, it shows me that `The connection has timed out. The server at www.reddit.com is taking too long to respond.` Here I was tried to open Reddit page. Even I am getting different public IP from curl command and Google. `curl ifconfig.co` gives me the public IPv4 address of AWS instance. And Google gives me the my device’s public IP, I was tried both IP address, but not works.

Comment: hi, I would like to suggest that you should use a VPN like wireguard as it not only supports any application moreover, it will route any traffic. Back to the Problem: test with lsof -i :8888 in case you used 8888 as the port. How did you prevent others from using your Proxy?

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to help you solve it. Check your application logs, check your security group. I also wonder if the AWS source / destination check needs to be disabled - I don't think so but it only takes a minute to try it https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#EIP_Disable_SrcDestCheck

Comment: @Tim Here is the all the details and screenshots of steps: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wGRByZDOIQhz5G_JfzzbjIilSFpjlRFv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @djdomi all the secure and trusted VPNs are paid with limited free trials. So, I want to decide to use my own proxy. Even I can monitor the traffic through this proxy and I can block certain websites, but I can't do that with VPN

Comment: If you want people to help you don't post a link to a huge PDF. Post a precise description of your problem, describe the diagnostics you've done, show some targeted logs (eg a curl with output, web server log entry, PHP error / access log entries, application log entries), that kind of thing. Show you've done some research yourself and make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: @chakrabarti that's not true because running your self-owned VPN is, I believe the most trusted way. A Proxy is just a public transfer that is at first unsecured as the initial connection is HTTP based, what I suggest is a VPN because you can redirect any connection to any destination, even like to force to your squid instances so it is in my mind the better solution. Don't forget to prevent unauthorized access to the Proxy, else the Internet will make you new friends to you 